# Relationship between probability distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Here I found a scheme summarizing relationships between distributions: https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/12/common-probability-distributions-the-data-scientists-crib-sheet/

However, I do not quite understand all the arrows between different distributions. For example, while Binomial is clearly derived from Bernoulli, what is meant by mutual relationship between for example, Binomial and Geometric. Or Uniform and Bernoulli.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you want...(Source: Wikipedia)
[image]